# Why this code is showing "unreachable code" error?? And how can I fix it?

Tags: java, unreachable-code

```java
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int[] arr= {5,6,9,-5,-2,4,-3,1,-1};
        
        int i=0;
        int n=arr.length;
        int j=n-1;
        while(true) 
            while(arr[i]>0 && i<j) {
                while(arr[j]<0 && i<j) {
                    if(i<j) {
                        int temp=arr[i];
                        arr[i]=arr[j];
                        arr[j]=temp;
                        i++;
                        j--;
                    }else 
                        break;
                }
                
            }
        for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++) {
            System.out.print(arr[x]+" "); //unreachable code
        }
    }
}
```

Why this code is showing "unreachable code" error?
And How can I fix it? how can I solve this error please help?

Comment: You have an infinite loop `while(true)` with no way out of it; how do you expect the `for` loop below should be reached? If you intend the `break` statement to exit from the outermost loop, you need to use a labelled break.

Comment: As a side note, I'd *strongly* recommend using braces even for single-statement loop/if bodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` leaves the nearest innermost loop it is in, in your case `while(arr[j]<0 && i<j)`. That means your `while(true)` is an infinite loop.

You can fix this by either maintaining a flag that will trigger an outer break:

```
boolean goOn = true;
while(goOn) 
    while(goOn && arr[i]>0 && i<j) {
        while(goOn && arr[j]<0 && i<j) {
            if(i<j) {
                int temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }else  {
                goOn = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++) {
    System.out.print(arr[x]+" "); //unreachable code
}
```

or create a label and `break` there:

```
while(true) 
    while(arr[i]>0 && i<j) {
        while(arr[j]<0 && i<j) {
            if(i<j) {
                int temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }else  {
                break exit;
            }
        }
        
    }
exit:
for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++) {
    System.out.print(arr[x]+" "); //unreachable code
}
```

The latter is a feature that is rarely used in Java.

Comment: @Saksham You need to move the `if(i < j)` check further outside. Since the same check is in the `while`-conditions, it will never reach the point it's currently at. Best to use a debugger to see what values `i` and `j` have in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It is all because of this line of code:

```
    while(true)
```

The rest of the code on the **for loop** will become unreachable because there is no way the first while loop will terminate  thus causing your program to be running on an infinite loop

**Unreachable code:**

```
for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++) {
    System.out.print(arr[x]+" "); //unreachable code
}
```

To fix you need to set a variable for the **first while** condition that would somehow change a value once a condition is met. Based on your code you can place it on the `else` part of your code:

```
boolean run = true;
while(run) {
        while(arr[i]>0 && i<j) {
            while(arr[j]<0 && i<j) {
                if(i<j) {
                    int temp=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=temp;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                } else {
                     run = false; 
                     break;
                 }
            }
            
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that the intention of the `break` is to leave all loops immediately; what you propose will still continue going through `while(arr[j]<0 && i<j)` and `while(arr[i]>0 && i<j)`.